# How can I redirect a subdomain using the root .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, dns

My goal is to edit the .htaccess file of a domain, for example, **example.com**, to add a variety of URL redirects such that:

- apple.example.com goes to example.org/subdomain1
- pear.example.com goes to example.org/subdomain2
- strawberry.example.com goes to example.org/subdomain3
- banana.example.com goes to example.org/subdomain4

How would I do this? Again, I only want to edit the root .htaccess file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^apple\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.org/subdomain1 [R=302,L]
```

The above redirects `https://apple.example.com/` to `https://example.org/subdomain1` as per your first example.

Etc.

---

#### Reference

- [Apache mod-rewrite Documentation - Contents](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/)
- **[Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)**
- [Apache mod_rewrite Reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

  - [`RewriteRule` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)
  - [`RewriteCond` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I have it on a live domain right now. I've cleared my cache and tried resaving and relocating the snippet in .htaccess. Any ideas? My web server usually updates instantly as it's LiteSpeed, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @wyatt400 What happens exactly?

Comment: Nothing, there aren't any errors on the hosting panel, just a DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE error in the browser. However, I've tried adding the snippet onto the .htaccess file of apple.example.com instead of the root example.com, and it works fine after a few seconds.

Comment: @wyatt400 Yes, you have to put this in the root of wherever the `apple` subdomain resolves to. Or a parent directory thereof (which has `.htaccess` overrides enabled). From your question I assumed all these subdomains pointed to the same place as the root of the main domain?

Comment: On my webserver, example.com seems to be a parent directory of apple.example.com. Should it work then?

Comment: Let me try enabling .htaccess overrides.

Comment: I've just noticed that I'm not the administrator of the server, so I guess this means I'll have to manually create a directory for each subdomain. Correct?

Comment: @wyatt400 "On my webserver, example.com seems to be a parent directory of apple.example.com. Should it work then?" - potentially, but it depends how the domain/subdomains are configured in the server config. "this means I'll have to manually create a directory for each subdomain. Correct?" - it depends what you are trying to do. You should be able to configure the directory that the subdomain points to (ie. the DocumentRoot) when you create the subdomain?